# Windows(variable).Activate error

Tags: excel, vba

```
Dim filepath As String
filepath = ActiveWorkbook.Path + "\"
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim file As String
Dim fullfilepath As String
file = Dir$(filepath & "*Example*" & ".*")
fullfilepath = filepath & file
Application.EnableEvents = False
Workbooks.Open (fullfilepath)
Windows(file).Activate
Application.EnableEvents = True
```

With the above code, it is quite happily populating the filepath, quite happily locating the file 'New Example.xlsm' and fullfilepath ends up correct too.

When it gets to Windows(file).Activate I get a subscript out of range error (before it even gets any further)

Is it something obvious? It works in another one of my coding examples.

Comment: That's odd, I ran your code and it worked fine for me. Have you tried it on another machine?

Comment: It was my own stupid mistake, I had the code stored under 'ThisWorkbook' instead of a seperate module or anything. Not really sure why that would cause it, but it did - thank you for trying it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim filepath As String
filepath = ActiveWorkbook.Path + "\"

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim file As String
Dim fullfilepath As String

file = Dir$(filepath & "*Example*" & ".*")
fullfilepath = filepath & file

Application.EnableEvents = False

Dim NewWB As Workbook
Set NewWB = Workbooks.Open (fullfilepath)

Set ActiveWindow = NewWB

Application.EnableEvents = True
```

I believe this is a little more elegant and easier to work with. If you declare NewWB either as static or as public variable then you can use this as a reference over multiple modules or subs. :)

Comment: Very helpful, thank you! Didn't think of doing it that way, it does make it a lot easier to work with - have a great weekend! :)

Comment: No problem and you too :)